# Not getting the selected Picker Id from model Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm totally new to Xamarin Forms. I want to get the selected picker item Id when user is going to submit data. Data is populating to picker without any issue.

Model Class

```
public class CurrentStatus
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string current_status { get; set; }
}

public enum CurrentStatusId
{
    NotApproved = 2,
    Approved = 3,
    Selected = 4,
    NotSelected = 5
}
```

I bounded the ID like this in my view.

```
<local:HCImagePicker x:Name="currentstatus" Title="Current Status" SelectedIndexChanged="HandleStatusItemChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentStatusId}" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentStatuses}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding current_status}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,10" Image="arrowdown" ImageAlignment="Right" ImageHeight="8" ImageWidth="12">
                        </local:HCImagePicker>
```

Just try to get the id after submiting data (In here simply I'm printing the value)

```
 public async void SubmitData(object sender, EventArgs e){


        var selectedId = currentstatus.SelectedItem;

        await DisplayAlert("TEST", "Id is"+ selectedId, "OK");


    }
```

Instead of getting a id (I don't want to get the selected value) , I'm getting a MyProject.Models.CurrentStatus.

Could someone help me to fix this.

Comment: have you checked CurrentStatusId value?
it could be
`var selectedId = CurrentStatusId ;`

Comment: check the value of selectedId.Id

Answer (score 2):

Without actually knowing how your HCImagePicker looks like, I guess that SelectedItem is probably of type object.

Therefore you need to cast it and access it's properties correctly:

```
CurrentStatus selectedStatus = (currentStatus.SelectedItem as CurrentStatus);
if (selectedStatus == null)
    return;
await DisplayAlert("TEST", "Id is"+ selectedStatus.id , "OK");
```

*Personal note:*
Do yourself a favour and don't use var. It might be comfortable and quick to use, however when it comes to casting around objects of any kind, you will definitely end up being confused, since you don't know what type of class you might end up with.

As far as I have experienced, using var instead of a proper type makes it harder to read and maintain your code in long term. Also you will be able to pinpoint possible error sources way faster when a cast goes wrong, because the compiler will warn you that what you attempt to do isn't possible.

Comment: it is a safeguard to prevent a NullReferenceException if the SelectedItem is null. If it you never set your selected item to null, you can omit it.

Comment: Just to know, Is it not a good standard to have a enum like this with model and access?

Comment: Using a datamodel with your view is good practise, however i am wondering why you don't use that enum inside your model für the status id. Also your model should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm for more details